# Ranking, treat a negative number as zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking, rank

Is there a way in Excel when ranking to treat a negative number as zero?

I have the following, but if I have multiple zeroes or negatives, I end up with duplicated ranks, which I cant have. I end up with:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ... 55

but i need

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ... 55

```
=IF($S79<0,RANK(0,$S$68:$S$121,0)+COUNTIF($S$68:$S79,0)-1,RANK($S79,$S$68:$S$121,0)+COUNTIF($S$68:$S79,$S79)-1)
```

Edit for clarification:

At the moment I have 55 rows. Rows 1-20 usually have a positive number, with the rest being zero. When I have a negative number, instead of it being placed in spot 21 (underneath all the positive numbers), it gets placed in spot 55 (because its less than zero).

So instead of

```
1 - 43%
2 - 35%
3 - 22%
4 - 0%
5 - 0%
6 - -20%
```

I'm after

```
1 - 43%
2 - 35%
3 - 22%
4 - 0%
5 - 0%
6 - 0% (treating the negative as zero, but visually still displaying the negative number)
```

Its for a weighted percentage leaderboard. I found a workaround by just adding a check for the percentages, something along the lines of "if % < 0 then 0 else %. Not exactly what I was after, but it will do. It stops people in the negative being placed at the bottom of the list i.e. spot 55.

I was getting:

```
1. Person 1 - 100%
2. Person 2 - 90%
3. Person 3 - 90%
4. Person 4 - 0%
5. Empty Slot - 0%
6. Empty Slot - 0%
7. Empty Slot - 0%
8. Person 5 - -50%
```

I want:

```
1. Person 1 - 100%
2. Person 2 - 90%
3. Person 3 - 90%
4. Person 4 - 0%
5. Person 5 - -50%
6. Empty Slot - 0%
7. Empty Slot - 0%
8. Empty Slot - 0%
```

Settled for (by adding a check where the % is generated):

```
1. Person 1 - 100%
2. Person 2 - 90%
3. Person 3 - 90%
4. Person 4 - 0%
5. Person 5 - 0%
6. Empty Slot - 0%
7. Empty Slot - 0%
8. Empty Slot - 0%
```

Comment: First you say you want to treat all negative numbers as 0, then you say you can't have duplicate entries? If negative numbers are considered as 0, you *will* have duplicate entries. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: Updated post for clarification.

Comment: See edits. Comment was too long..

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need the `LARGE` function. You can use this formula:

```
= MAX(LARGE($A$2:$A$10,ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1),0)
```

(But just change these ranges to whatever your ranges are)

See below for an example. Column `A` contains the data and column `B` sorts the data with the largest at the top, and considers any negative numbers as just `0`.

[image]